# Maintain white-spaces in Data when using extjs

Tags: javascript, php, css, extjs

I have a DB which contains some data for eg. employee records, suppose one record has a text field as "Hel (multiple spaces) lo" , then at front end also I want data to be displayed must be "Hel (multiple spaces) lo" but not as "Hel lo" i.e.Extra white spaces must be provided. I am using ext.js to render the html, Is this the attribute of ext.js

Comment: It always gets displayed with multiple spaces only. You need to show code or something to understand the issue.

Comment: @HarshitShah you can consider this example, http://jsfiddle.net/rixo/vdazU/

I won't to give atleast 5 spaces in between First page, how to achieve that ?

Comment: In your question you had asked for a textfield, so for that it does. For grid data in your example, the spaces are trimmed. For that, need to look into it.

Comment: @HarshitShah pls consider the example which I shared as my main question

Comment: How are you showing textfield's data means where and how ? So that we can identify what may be wrong

Answer (score 1):

Style responsible for rendering white space is `white-space`.

Based on your description i think you'll want either `white-space:pre` or `white-space:pre-wrap`

Here's an example of one way of applying this style to a column:

```
Ext.util.CSS.createStyleSheet(
    '.custom-whitespace .x-grid-cell-inner { white-space:pre }'
);

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),

    title: 'StackOverflow: Maintain white-spaces in Data when using extjs',

    columns: [{
        header: 'col',
        flex: 1,
        dataIndex: 'field1',
        tdCls: 'custom-whitespace'
    }],

    store: [
        ['one two three'],
        ['four five    six'],
        ['seven eight nine']
    ]
});
```

Also available in a [sencha fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/20he) for your convenience.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify `renderer` config in column and you have replace `space` with `&nbsp;`

```
renderer: function(value){
   return value.replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "&nbsp;");
}
```